# Printing and replacing numbers and percentages in C++

Tags: c++

So I am new to coding in C++
and I want to make a loading number.
like, I want to print 1% then after some time delete it and replace it with 2% on the same place as the 1% was.
I know about the sleep command but I do not know how to replace the previous number% with a new number% I would like to be able to repeat it until 100%
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This may depend on your terminal that you are using. ncurses may be an option for this. [https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Using_ncurses_library_with_C](https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/Using_ncurses_library_with_C) If your on windows you may want to use the windows api console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << 'a'; // so we have something to delete
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
        std::cout << '\b' << i << std::flush;
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You know how '\n' is newline? '\b' is backspace.
Edit for 100:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "a%"; // so we have something to delete
    int last = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 101 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < std::to_string(last).length()+1; j++) std::cout << '\b';
        std::cout << i <<'%'<< std::flush;
        sleep(1);
        last = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Will work for any digit. Can be optimized by not having to delete every digit, but anyways, this is good enough.

Comment: Yes that counts up numbers 0 to 5 thank you very much, but if I put it above 10 it keeps adding new numbers, I assume that is because it is an int and not string, how do I fix this so it goes onto 100? also, how do i add the percent symbol? i have tried adding new lines and putting a new std: :court behind it, those things to not work. any tips?

Comment: if the string is the at the beginning of your line \r for 'carriage-return' or 'move cursor all the way to the left of the current-line' might work for you,.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int percent=1;
    while(percent<101)
    {
        cout << timer<<" %" <<endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        --timer;
    }
    cout << "Percent count completed  :)\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Sleep(1000);` would require including windows.h somehow. With that said it does not replace the old line like the question asks instead it adds additional lines.